# Adding comment in raw string literal

Tags: c++

I have a raw string literal:

```
const char* s1 = R"foo(
Hello
  World
)foo";
```

I would like to add a comment inside this string literal, e.g.:

```
const char* s1 = R"foo(
Hello
// Say hello to the whole world because we don't know who will run the program.
  World
)foo";
```

This comment is actually used as part of the string. Is there any way to escape this comment to be parsed as an actual comment (or does that defeat the purpose of a **raw** string)?

I can obviously do ugly things like split the string in two add a comment between the two parts and concatenate them but I am looking for something more elegant.

Comment: no, you can't put a comment inside any kind of string literal, adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated though

Comment: Put the comment , before, after the string or split the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest thing is to "escape it" with the raw string end and start delimiters:

```
const char* s1 = R"foo(
Hello)foo"
// Say hello to the whole world because we don't know who will run the program.
R"foo(
  World
)foo";
```

Comment: This loses the new line between hello and world. You would need to add it (which is part of why I found this solution undesirable since it introduces small hard to find bugs like that).

Comment: @Jarod42 and BenjyKessler. Thanks for pointing this out. I have modified the answer to mimic the exact string. The conclusion is still that I think this is the least bad answer with the limitations of the C++ grammar.

Comment: @BenjyKessler: I would say that is it the raw string split where `\n` might be omitted easily, with `"\n" "Hello\n" /* some comment */ "  World\n"` eol is more explicit.